# Javascript not logging response given by Flask application

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have the following files
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id = "input_thing">

<button id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</button>

<script src='script.js'></script>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("input_thing").value;
  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url=' https://*****.****.**/doctorapi/'+x;
    fetch(url).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.json());
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=response.json();
      })
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to print the response to a request I send. The website which I created is receiving requests.

Here is some of that code

```
@app.route('/doctorapi/<query>')
def next(query):
    respons = query_search(query)
    respons=str(respons)
    response = make_response(jsonify(

        {
            "medical_response":respons,
            "query":query

            }
        ))
    return response
```

and when I go on my browser, I see the response. However, the JS isn't getting that JSON and logs and empty string. How do I fix this? What's the correct way of sending a request>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `json()` function of the response object is asynchronous. It therefore returns an object of the `Promise` type. To get the final result, it must either be expected with the `await` keyword or processed in a subsequent `then`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="search-form">
      <input type="text" name="query" />
      <button type="submit">Click me</button>
    </form>
    <output name="search-result"></output>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (() => {
        const formElem = document.querySelector('form[name="search-form"]');
        formElem.addEventListener('submit', event => {
          event.preventDefault();
          fetch(`/doctorapi/${encodeURIComponent(event.target.query.value)}`)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => {
              const outElem = document.querySelector('output[name="search-result"]');
              outElem.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
            });
        });
      })()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
@app.route('/doctorapi/<query>')
def search(query):
    data = 'my-search-result'
    return jsonify(query=query, results=data)
```